# Phaser 3, function doesn't exist/not defined

Tags: phaser-framework, phaserjs

I have a npc class which has a method called `chase` that is referenced inside the `update` function. when `chase` is called it says its not a function or it's not defined. I have another method being referenced in the same way that works.

```
chase()
{
    this.Phaser.Physics.moveToObject(NPC_spr, player_spr, 100);
    this.anims.play('NPC',true);
}
```

chase method in npcClass.js

```
bullet_ary = bulletGroup.getChildren();

for (let bullet_spr of bullet_ary)
{
     bullet_spr.updateMe();
}

NPC_ary = npcGroup.getChildren()

for (let npc_spr of NPC_ary)
{
    npc_spr.chase();
}
```

`chase` is called at `npc_spr.chase();` which is in the update function, this creates an error while above the `bullet_spr.updateMe()` works. `updateMe` is also a method.

what I expected to happen was for the method to be called like the one above for the bullets. I have tried many different ways of rewriting it but everything results in the not defined or not a function error.

Error in console - Uncaught TypeError: npc_spr.chase is not a function

npcGroup code

```
npcGroup = this.add.group({key: 'NPC'});

npcGroup.createMultiple({key: 'NPC', repeat: 10 })

 npcGroup.children.iterate(function(child)
{
child.setPosition(Phaser.Math.Between(0,  config.height, 0), Phaser.Math.Between(0,  config.width, 0));
})
```

Comment: Here some points you should address, so that we can help you, 1) it is always better to post real code, not screenshots of code.  2)  Please update your question with some vital information, like: What is the exact error message in the browser console?  Info where is the `npc_spr.chase()` called? can you share more code(but only relevant parts)? Here is a article outlining [how to write a good question, that receive answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you fro updating your question, but I would need more code or more context. Is `npc_spr` a custom sprite? can you share that class (or at least the relevant parts)?  And the code where you create the `npcGroup` group? or the relevant parts from the `create` function?

Comment: npc_spr is created at 'for (let npc_spr of NPC_ary)' its accessing the method 'Chase()' from the class 'NPC'. the bullet_spr above does the same thing and works. I will add the npcgroup code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are creating simple "Sprite" GameObjects and not from you Custom NPC class (except if you built a custom plugin, that adds that functionality). Since the group create function should create usually only sprite  GameObject, if you don't define the `classType`.

So the solution would have to be, simply alter this line:

```
npcGroup = this.add.group({key: 'NPC'});
```

too look like this:

```
npcGroup = this.add.group({key: 'NPC', classType: NPC });
```

Then the error should disappear.

**Here a short working Demo:**
*(showcasing the difference between "custom class group" and "sprite group")*

The custom sprite rotates.

```js
console.clear();
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

class NPC extends Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite {
    constructor (scene, x, y) {
        super(scene, x, y);

        this.setTexture('NPC');
        this.setPosition(x, y);
    }

    // just to show some difference
    preUpdate (time, delta){
        super.preUpdate(time, delta);
        this.rotation += 0.01;
    }

}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        create
    },
}; 

function createNPCTextureForDemo(scene) {
  let graphics  = scene.make.graphics();
  graphics.fillStyle(0xffffff);
  graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
  graphics.generateTexture('NPC', 20, 20);
}

function create () {

    createNPCTextureForDemo(this);
    this.add.text(10,10, 'Group created with "classType" => CustomSprite')
        .setScale(1.25)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});
    
   let classGroup = this.add.group({classType: NPC, quantity:0 });
   classGroup.createMultiple({key:'NPC', quantity: 3, setXY: {x: 50, y: 50, stepX: 25} });
        
   this.add.text(10, 90, 'Group created without "classType" => Sprite')
        .setScale(1.25)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

   let noClassGroup = this.add.group();
   noClassGroup.createMultiple({key:'NPC', quantity: 3, setXY: {x: 50, y: 150, stepX: 25}  });

}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```